# Passbook - storeCard design with ticks

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, passbook, wallet

I want to be able to design a storeCard that works as a punch card. Every time someone buys a bread one more punch will need to appear on his pass.

Should looks something similar to the design below.

[image]

The image withe the circles is strip@2x.png. What is the best way to update that? I am thinking to change the image with a new one every time I sent push notification and the pass gets an update. But from the documentation I am not sure if I can do that... from the documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/Updating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012195-CH5-SW1

```
To send the list of serial numbers, do the following:

Look at the registrations table, and determine which passes the device is registered for.

Look at the passes table, and determine which passes have changed since the given tag. Don’t include serial numbers of passes that the device didn’t register for. If no update tag is provided, return all the passes that the device is registered for. For example, you return all registered passes the very first time a device communicates with your server.

Compare the update tags for each pass that has changed and determine which one is the latest. Return the latest update tag to the device.

Respond with this list of serial numbers and the latest update tag in a JSON payload. For example:

{
    "serialNumbers" : ["001", "020", "3019"],
    "lastUpdated" : "1351981923"
}
```

How can I approach this? Do I try to update the whole pass every time when a new push message comes? Is that how the update is done or just some bits of the json file (pass.json) are changed? Is there more clever way to achieve this?

Comment: I think I find my answer later - somehow the server must return the whole pass if changed.... still that seems complicated - I will need to build the image on the fly, check what is the latest version on the client and then if changed return the whole thing but not just some bits of it... and I guess should be zipped package with images and signed resources.... complicated...

Comment: You're right. You'll need to return an updated pass. However, you should be able to use the pass' serial number to determine the number of stamps and to then create a pass on the fly. Creating a pass on the fly would no more or less difficult than creating the pass in the first place. You wouldn't need to generate the image on the fly, instead just main 10 images, each one with a different number of stamps.

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness maybe 20 images as we have strip.png and strip@2x.png That's very difficult to setup and test...  will start the digging in ...

Comment: @TomasMcGuinness hi, do you know how to get credentials to be able to send push notifications for pass? When selecting "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)" from the options then I need to specify App ID - bundle for app which is not relevant when sending push for pass? Can you point me to good tutorial?

Comment: You use same certificate as the one used to sign your passes.